# How many breakpoints for mobile devices in responsive design and mobile native apps?

Tags: mobile, mobile-application, responsive-design, responsive

In a browser based app with responsive design, how many breakpoints are needed? Have you done any projects as an example, and what are the best industry practices?

I normally see only 3 breakpoints; smallest mobile devices at 320px, iPad at 768px and another one at 1200px for desktop.

Secondly, for a native app, how many versions of mobile screen size are needed?

Answer (score 2):

[Bootstrap, a very popular framework, uses 4 breakpoints, as below:](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

> /* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
>   /* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */
>
> /* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
>   @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }
>
> /* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
>   @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }
>
> /* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
>   @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }